# merge pcap files

Tags: wireshark

I'm trying to merge 15 pcap files using wireshark. The merging is successful. I'm using appending function so that the second file is just added to the bottom of the first file. But when this is done, I get -ve value in time column. How can I change this? What I intend to do is, replace these 15 smaller files with this one merged files. 
[image]

Comment: time offsets are relative to the time if the first frame. You'll want to merge the frames instead of concatenating the files. See the `mergecap` command.

Answer (score 9):

You need to use `mergecap` without the -a option. This will merge them chronologically based on packet timestamp.

```
mergecap -w mergedfile.pcap files*.pcap
```

http://www.wireshark.org/docs/man-pages/mergecap.html

Answer (score 2):

This can be done using [joincap](https://github.com/assafmo/joincap).

```
go get -u github.com/assafmo/joincap
```

To merge `1.pcap` and `2.pcap`:

```
joincap 1.pcap 2.pcap > merged.pcap
```

I wrote `joincap` to overcome what I believe is bad error handling by `mergecap` and `tcpslice`.
For more details go to https://github.com/assafmo/joincap.